# How to use Laravel 5 to receive Amazon SNS message from SQS?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, laravel-5, amazon-sqs, amazon-sns

I am trying to get the email response (bounce, complaint and delivery) from Amazon SES through SNS. On Amazon SQS console, I see that the message is already in the queue, so I am sure the setting for structures on Amazon is correct.

Then, using Laravel 5.5, following the [official guide](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queues), I set up a queue listening to SQS. I skip the part of dispatching jobs to the queue as this will be done by SNS. In the job handler, for simplicity, I just `var_dump` what I receive. The job looks like this:

```
public function handle($testing_message)
{
    var_dump($testing_message);
    echo "testing handle!\n";
}
```

The config for that looks something like this:

```
'sqs' => [
    'driver' => 'sqs', //mainly to show that I am using the correct driver
    'key' => env('SQS_KEY', 'your-public-key'),
    'secret' => env('SQS_SECRET', 'your-secret-key'),
    'prefix' => env('SQS_PREFIX', 'https://sqs.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/your-account-id'),
    'queue' => env('SQS_QUEUE', 'your-queue-name'),
    'region' => env('SQS_REGION', 'us-east-1'),
],
```

For security, The actual value is hidden in `.env`. I then run:

```
composer require aws/aws-sdk-php ~3.0
php artisan config:cache
php artisan queue:listen
```

However, the process just sit there running, no response and no error message.

I want to ask:

1. How do I know if the connection to the queue is correct?
2. If the connection is correct, why there is no return from SQS? (I am sure there are already message inside SQS queue from the Amazon console)

Comment: try: php artisian queue:listen -vvv

Comment: @albert May I know what is that `-vvv` for?

Comment: Verbose debug level

Comment: @albert still no error and response.

Comment: try `php artisan queue:work` instead of listen. If nothing happens, try with sync, which helps to debug whats wrong on your code.

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this in the end?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you are using a queue rather than a simple https endpoint.  That removes a lot of complexity and doesn't require polling.

There is a [simple php example](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/receiving-amazon-sns-messages-in-php-2/) that shows what is needed.

The biggest gotcha is that you need to be able to confirm the SNS subscription before SNS will start sending POST requests to your endpoint.

Comment: We stop sending out email during 00:00-08:00 due to some operation policy. Thus, we would expect an sudden busy sending (thus response) traffic at 8:00 (or maybe other time when policy change), so a queue would be a nice way to handle the traffic peak?

Comment: You could always use API gateway + Lambda if scaling is an issue.

Comment: True, but you can always use node or python.  What type of volume do you expect to handle at 8am?  You could spin up a cluster via autoscaling scheduled events just to handle the SNS posts, but honestly unless you're sending millions of emails/hr load probably isn't an issue.

Comment: Sigh.... it is a long story. The system is built for a customer and will be hand over to them after the system is on production. They only have programmers that are only willing to use PHP. They have server running other application and want us to use the same server to cut cost. Lambda's low cost is still okay for them, but a EC2 with the config they are asking for is too expansive for them.  Anyway, customer is always right. It may sounds unreasonable, but we don't have a choice.

Comment: If you're talking about a system that runs on "a server" then you're not sending much.  An http endpoint will be fine.